# how to run complex awk command on remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ssh

I am trying to capture the total used memory in % on remote machine as the following

```
 sshpass -p pasa123 ssh root@server01 "  /usr/bin/free | awk '/Mem/{printf("RAM Usage: %.2f%\n"), $3/$2*100}' "
awk: cmd. line:1: /Mem/{printf(RAM Usage: %.2f%n), /*100}
awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /Mem/{printf(RAM Usage: %.2f%n), /*100}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /Mem/{printf(RAM Usage: %.2f%n), /*100}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                   ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: /Mem/{printf(RAM Usage: %.2f%n), /*100}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                        ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

so we add backslash as before the "$" as

```
 sshpass -p pasa123 ssh root@server01 "  /usr/bin/free | awk '/Mem/{printf("RAM Usage: %.2f%\n"), \$3/\$2*100}' "
```

but still with the same errors

any advice how to fix this syntax?

Comment: You could put the script in a file and run it with `awk -f` if the quoting is too difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to escape the double quotes `"`:

```
sshpass -p pasa123 ssh root@server01 "/usr/bin/free | awk '/Mem/{printf(\"RAM Usage: %.2f%\n\"), \$3/\$2*100}' "
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to process it on your local machine. Ask ssh to provide you with the output of `/usr/bin/free` and use `awk` locally:

```
sshpass -p pasa123 ssh root@server01 /usr/bin/free | awk '/Mem/{printf("RAM Usage: %.2f%\n"), $3/$2*100}'
```

Three comments here:

1. don't ssh as root!
2. don't use `sshpass -p`.
3. don't ssh as root in combination with `sshpass -p`, really don't!

With a simple `df` issued at the right time, any user can read your root password on the fly.

I strongly advice you to start using public key authentication and abandon the use of `sshpass -p`!